# Decreasing quantity of items when checking out from shopping cart - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am building mini online shop project for collage.
Clients can add multiple products to cart , and also update their cart like decreasing and adding quantity of same item. I am having trouble with decreasing quantity of products at the end. So when customer checks out from cart, original quantity of deferent items changes in database.
Here is the View for Cart.cshtml :

```
@model CartViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Cart Overview";
}


@if (Model.CartItems.Count > 0)
{
    <h1>Cart Overview</h1>
    <div class="cartWrapper">
        <div class="cartbg d-none">
            <h3 class="text-center">Redirecting you to paypal...</h3>
            <img src="~/Images/ajax_loader.gif" />
        </div>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.ProductName</td>
                    <td>@item.Quantity</td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="Add" asp-route-id="@item.ProductId" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">+</a>
                        <a asp-action="Decrease" asp-route-id="@item.ProductId" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">-</a>
                        <a asp-action="Remove" asp-route-id="@item.ProductId" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Remove</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>@item.Price.ToString("C2")</td>
                    <td>@Model.CartItems.Where(x => x.ProductId == item.ProductId).Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.Price).ToString("C2")</td>
                </tr>
            }
            <tr>
                <td class="text-right" colspan="4">Grand total: @Model.GrandTotal.ToString("C2")</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-right" colspan="4">
                    <a asp-action="Clear" class="btn btn-danger">Clear cart</a>
                    <a asp-action="Checkout" asp-controller="Cart"  class="btn btn-primary checkout">Checkout</a>
                    


                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <h3 class="display-4 text-center">Cart is empty</h3>

}
<partial name="~/Views/Cart/_PayPalPartial.cshtml" for="CartItems" />
@section Scripts{
    <script>
    $(function () {

        $("a.checkout").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("div.cartbg").removeClass("d-none");
            $.get("/cart/clear", {}, function () {

                $("form.paypalform").submit();
            });
            
        });

    });

    </script>

}
```

And also CartController.cs :

```
    using CmsShoppingCart.Infrastructure;
    using CmsShoppingCart.Models;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    namespace CmsShoppingCart.Controllers
    {
        public class CartController : Controller
        {
            private readonly CmsSchoppingCartContext context;
            public CartController(CmsSchoppingCartContext context)
            {
                this.context = context;
            }
            //GET /cart
            public IActionResult Index()
            {
                List<CartItem> cart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<List<CartItem>>("Cart") ?? new List<CartItem>();
    
                CartViewModel cartVM = new CartViewModel
                {
                    CartItems = cart,
                    GrandTotal = cart.Sum(x => x.Price * x.Quantity)
                };
                return View(cartVM);
            }
            //GET /cart/add/id
            public async Task<IActionResult> Add(int id)
            {
                Product product = await context.Products.FindAsync(id);
                List<CartItem> cart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<List<CartItem>>("Cart") ?? new List<CartItem>();
                CartItem cartItem = cart.Where(x => x.ProductId == id).FirstOrDefault();
                if (cartItem == null)
                {
                    cart.Add(new CartItem(product));
                }
                else
                {
                    cartItem.Quantity += 1;
                }
                HttpContext.Session.SetJson("Cart", cart);
                if(HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] != "XMLHttpRequest")
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
    
    
    
                return ViewComponent("SmallCart");
                
            }
            //GET /cart/decrease/id
            public IActionResult Decrease(int id)
            {
    
                List<CartItem> cart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<List<CartItem>>("Cart");
                CartItem cartItem = cart.Where(x => x.ProductId == id).FirstOrDefault();
                if (cartItem.Quantity > 1)
                {
                    --cartItem.Quantity;
                }
                else
                {
                    cart.RemoveAll(x => x.ProductId == id);
                }
             
                if (cart.Count == 0)
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.Remove("Cart");
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetJson("Cart", cart);
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            //GET /cart/remove/id
            public IActionResult Remove(int id)
            {
    
                List<CartItem> cart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<List<CartItem>>("Cart");
    
                cart.RemoveAll(x => x.ProductId == id);
    
                if (cart.Count == 0)
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.Remove("Cart");
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetJson("Cart", cart);
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            //GET /cart/clear
            public IActionResult Clear()
            {
                HttpContext.Session.Remove("Cart");
    
    
    
                // return RedirectToAction("Page", "Pages");
                //return Redirect("/");
                if (HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] != "XMLHttpRequest")
                    return Redirect(Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString());
                return Ok();
            }
 public IActionResult Checkout()
        {
            List<CartItem> cart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<List<CartItem>>("Cart") ?? new List<CartItem>();

            //Quentity +/- Database

            for (int i = 0; i < cart.Count; i++)
            {

                var t = context.Products.Single(x => x.Id == cart[i].ProductId);


                if (t?.Quantity > 0)
                {
                    t.Quantity = (t.Quantity - cart[i].Quantity);

                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            return Ok();
        }
        }
    }
```

and cart model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CmsShoppingCart.Models
{
    public class CartItem
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get { return Quantity * Price; }  }
        public string Image { get; set; }

        public CartItem()
        {

        }
        public CartItem(Product product)
        {
            ProductId = product.Id;
            ProductName = product.Name;
            Price = product.Price;
            Quantity = 1;
            Image = product.Image;

        }
    }
    
}
```

PayPal partial View:

```
@{ 
    int count = 1;
}
<form class="paypalform" action="https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="zamorac.niksa@gmail.com">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_@count" value="@item.ProductName" />
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_@count" value="@item.Price" />
        <input type="hidden" name="quantitiy_@count" value="@item.Quantity" />
        count++;
    }
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
 
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you clarify specifically where you're having a problem in this code?  When you debug, which specific operation is producing an unexpected result?

Comment: @David There is no problem in this current code, I just don't know how to do it...

Comment: @judy_may please clarify.what's your problem and what you actually want.

Comment: @PritomSarkar my problem is that I don't know how to decrease quantity of different product when they are bought / on cart checkout, I do not know how to decrease value of quantity of products in database.

Comment: @judy_may so you want to decrease your product quantity from the session and also from your Database right?

Comment: @PritomSarkar yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed, you `CartItem` table has contain `Quantity` data.

```
List<CartItem> cart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<List<CartItem>>("Cart") ?? new List<CartItem>();

//Quentity +/- Database

       for (int i = 0; i < cart .Count; i++)
                {

                    var t = _db.CartItem.Single(x => x.ProductId  == cart[i].ProductId );


                    if (t?.Quantity > 0)
                    {
                        t.Quantity = (t.Quantity - cart [i].Quantity);

                        _db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
```

So for that, after checkout when the client confirms, the quantity will be updated in your Database.

**UPDATE**

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Add(int id)
            {
                Product product = await context.Products.FindAsync(id);
                List<CartItem> cart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<List<CartItem>>("Cart") ?? new List<CartItem>();
                CartItem cartItem = cart.Where(x => x.ProductId == id).FirstOrDefault();
               
                if (cartItem == null)
                {
                    cart.Add(new CartItem(product));
                }
                else
                {
                    cartItem.Quantity += 1;
                    product.Quantity--;      //just do it for decrease quantity for add
                    context.SaveChanges();   

                }

                HttpContext.Session.SetJson("Cart", cart);
                if(HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] != "XMLHttpRequest")
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
    
                return ViewComponent("SmallCart");
                
            }



             //GET /cart/decrease/id
            public IActionResult Decrease(int id)
            {
                Product product = await context.Products.FindAsync(id);  //add this
                List<CartItem> cart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<List<CartItem>>("Cart");
                CartItem cartItem = cart.Where(x => x.ProductId == id).FirstOrDefault();
                if (cartItem.Quantity > 1 && product.Quantity > 1)
                {
                    --cartItem.Quantity;
                    product.Quantity++;   //just do it for increase quantity for add
                    context.SaveChanges(); 
                }
                else
                {
                    cart.RemoveAll(x => x.ProductId == id);
                }
             
                if (cart.Count == 0)
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.Remove("Cart");
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetJson("Cart", cart);
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

so the solution is simple,when you dynamically increase/decrease your quantity,it's automaticly update also in your DB.for that you will found expected quantity in your paypalpartial view.

Comment: @judy_may Check my answer.please let me know is it work or not

Comment: I tried it but nothing happpend, I think it doesn't work because something with my paypal checkout does not work. I have put this code in my Cart Controller in new method named checkout and then added <a> link with asp-action="checkout"(in cart paypal view). As I tried to debug it it seems it does not even enter the method...So I can guess that the code you wrote works, because it look fine to me, but I have other mistakes in code probably....

Comment: @judy_may so you say did not enter the method which is my posted functionality.if you do enter your method, definitely will work as expected.you can post your cart Paypal view. I will check it out.

Comment: @judy_may it's better if you process product update quantity in your DB before go to the partial view. for that partial view works on updated  quantity.

Comment: can you specify where exactly to update db in which part of the code? @pritom

Comment: @judy_may i updated my answer,please check.